# Set a column full of duplicate entries to PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql

I have about 100,000 rows of unique data. The client said he wants a column called `id` to be auto_incrementing and the primary key. Right now, it's full of 0s. How exactly would I go about this?

When I try to set it to auto_increment MySQL says the column needs to be primary and there can only be 1 auto_increment column.

When I try to set it as the primary key, it says duplicate entries, because all of my rows in that column contain "0".

Comment: Update column values first. Then change column attributes.

Comment: What do I update them to when I want them to just auto increment from 1?

Comment: You can do it with variable. But, please share your table structure and sample data, and let see, if we can update them with other column and without using variables.

Comment: Added a screenshot above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend dropping the ID column and re-creating it like so:

```
create table test (id int, name varchar(50));
insert into test values (0, 'john'), (0, 'matt'), (0, 'tom');

alter table test add primary key(id);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

alter table test drop id;
alter table test add id int primary key auto_increment;

select * from test;
+------+----+
| name | id |
+------+----+
| john |  1 |
| matt |  2 |
| tom  |  3 |
+------+----+
```

Make a backup of your data first, though!